# Unable to get cookie in construct function

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I'm trying to set the cookie variable in the construct function, but its setting a hashed variable like below when I do `Cookie::get('cookie_name');` in the construct.

```
eyJpdiI6ImRnRWF3TEa82Wm9cL3lRbng0OW1Wc1FBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlI4TkgwZGd6Mn
```

Below is the code I'm trying.

```
class CookieController extends Controller
{
    public $cookie;
    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->cookie = Cookie::get('cookie_name');
    }

    public function viewCookie(Request $request){
    return $this->cookie;
    }
```

If I call the `Cookie::get('cookie_name');` inside the viewCookie function then its showing the correct value. Is the Cookie class disabled in the construct function?

Comment: is the session started before the construct is called?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's related to 5.3 changes for [using sessions in controller constructor](https://laravel-news.com/2016/08/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3/). Here's an explanation from Taylor Otwell:

> It’s very bad to use session or auth in your constructor as no request has happened yet and session and auth are INHERENTLY tied to an HTTP request. You should receive this request in an actual controller method which you can call multiple times with multiple different requests. By forcing your controller to resolve session or auth information in the constructor you are now forcing your entire controller to ignore the actual incoming request which can cause significant problems when testing, etc.